# App Crashing without calling Unhandled Exception method Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for both WP7 and WP8.
So i finished the WP7 part and it is working properly and now I have updated the target version to Windows Phone 8 and my app crashes without notifying anything.
In xaml designer it shows an error like:

```
Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
```

I do not understand how to solve this as I have tried the methods available on internet telling to copy a .dll file from one location to another but that also didn't worked in my case.

Xaml of page before it crashes ...

```
 x:Class="Climatech.View.AddDeviceView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:toolkit1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:controlsPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    DataContext="{Binding AddDeviceModel,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
```

Can anybody help me with this or at least guide me to where the problem is ...

Comment: Can you copy paste your top xaml part of the first page. It is probably in that section.

Comment: that is too big code as i have opned the styles of many conrtols and edited them ..

Comment: Then it is hard to see anything. I was thinking about the using statements in xaml if you get what I mean :) and not the entire xaml code.

Comment: i have added the code please check....

Comment: Are you using MVVMLight? Then I would use DataContext as  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=AddDeviceModel}" The other code I cant find a problem sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting demo on debugging WP apps here, perhaps there may be something that you haven't tried that might help nail down the issue..
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-578